# Moment.js: load locales on demand

Tags: momentjs

Is there any way to load (make the HTTP request) Moment.js locale files only when they're about to be used?

I'd like to load vanilla Moment.js and only request another locale file once the user opts to change the language of the UI, so that app isn't unnecessarily bloated.